# Default value for selection type range in List Report(Fiori Elements)

Tags: sap-fiori

I have created a List report application based on Fiori elements.

In my CDS, i have defined below property for filter :

```
@UI.selectionField: [{position: 80 }]
@Consumption.filter.selectionType: #RANGE

header.diffrence as DayNo,
```

Requirement is to display default value of filter (DayNo) less than equal to '5',

```
 @Consumption.filter.defaultValue
```

gives only 'equal to' values.

Is it possible to set default selection operator to 'less than equal'?

regards,

Umar Abdullah